# CSS zoom - with static border width

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, zooming

Can it be done - crossbrowser (IE9, Mozilla, Chrome, Opera) ?

In this snippet `.box` border is affected by `zoom` property. Can this be avoided ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.box {
     zoom: 3;
     -moz-transform: scale(3);  /* FF fix */
     border: 1px dotted black;
     padding:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4q42E/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4q42E/2/

Comment: @jumpingcode Internet Explorer doesn't support decimal width.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you expect here. If you apply the `zoom` property to any element, then all of it's measurements will be transformed by `1/x`. Away your example, the best way to do this would be to divide the intended measurements by the value of your zoom. In your example, if you wanted to keep padding at `10px` (or thereabouts), you'd use `padding:3px` instead.

However, because your issue is with the `border` property and specifically, having set `1px` as the value, you can't divide this by your `zoom` value. Instead, you're going to have to wrap HTML around it:

```
<div class="border">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

And move your border styling from `.box` to `.border`

***[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q42E/3/)***